# How to test prepend_view_path method using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The controller has differents views based on current site. The code look like this:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  prepend_view_path :prepend_templates_path

  private
  def get_views_path
    "public/assets/#{current_site.slug}/views"
  end
end
```

How to test that Rails is searching inside `"public/assets/#{current_site.slug}/views"` folder for views?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't directly test that Rails (or any other client software) is searching within a particular directory for something unless you know which specific methods it is calling and when it is calling them. You can readily check that the result of calling `view_path` changes as a result of your `prepend_view_path` call, however.

Comment: Peter, I tried to check `@controller.class.view_paths`, but the PathSet has only the symbol that represents the method to be called, `prepend_templates_path`. If exists any way to execute this method, I can test the result path

Comment: I'm not sure how you're examining the `PathSet` or if there's another way to extract the path names, but `@controller.class.view_paths.map {|vp| vp.to_s}` should give you the array.

Comment: I inspect with `@controller.class.view_paths.map { |vp| vp.original_path_set.paths }`.

Comment: Did you try the code I suggested in my previous comment?